# How to prevent running a command in a Docker image

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Docker. The image I am using is kaggle/python https://github.com/Kaggle/docker-python/blob/main/Dockerfile

Using this image, I would like to create a new image which:

(1) Has some more packages

(2) Prevents Jupyter from starting up automatically each time the container is run (the source image does this - I can't seem to find the command in the docker file where this is invoked)

Edit:
I have found the line where Jupyter is invoked, however I am unsure as to how it can get ignored in my new image

```
python -m nb_conda_kernels.install --disable
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You gave a list of requirements, but you did not ask a specific question. --- Docker images are inherently immutable.

Comment: modified the question

Comment: You modified the post. A question is still missing. --- Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- I recommend taking a look at the [official dockkerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), in particular the `FROM`, `RUN`, `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` instructions.

Comment: What _do_ you want the container to do when it starts up?

Comment: I am using the container as a remote interpreter in my IDE. I only want this image for the packages and general environment which it mandates

Comment: did you pull the Kaggle image first?  I would do that, sit back, start an herb garden, when it's time to harvest, the pull will be done then we move on from there.

Comment: Yes I have the image. When I run it in docker, it does loads everything and at the last step it starts up the Jupyter server. Hitting ctrl+c twice is supposed to terminate it (as the terminal message claims) but that command is ineffective. It usually works outside of Docker for me

Comment: did you try ```docker run -it --entrypoint bin/bash kaggle/python```?

Comment: That worked. Here is the output of `ls`: ```root@d456d6f55ba1:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  entrypoint.sh  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  run_jupyter.sh  sbin  src  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var``` -- So it looks like run_jupyter.sh is the culprit. How do I remove that from my cloned image?

Comment: Here is a quick Dockerfile that will override the base images entrypoint: ```FROM kaggle/python

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/env" ]
RUN ["bash"]```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236713/discussion-between-glacecelery-and-martin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This barebones Dockerfile should get you going.

```
FROM kaggle/python

# Add more stuff here, for example
# RUN pip install Boruta
# RUN apt-get install -y graphviz && pip install graphviz

# if you make your own startup script called entrypoint.sh:
# WORKDIR /
# COPY entrypoint.sh .

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/env" ]

# if you made your own startup script
# RUN ["/entrypoint.sh"]
# else
RUN ["bash"]
```